# enable select element when the previous select has a selected value

Tags: jquery, mysql, asp.net

I have two cascaded select elements. When I retrieve data from database the first select element has its selected value respective to database but the second select does not get enabled as it should do if there is an option selected in first select..

```
     function GetProSpl() {
$("select#program").prepend(new Option("Select Program", "0"));
    $("select#program").val("0");
    $('#specializn').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    $('#specializn').append('<option value="0">Select Specialization</option>');   

$('#program').change(function () {
    var programid = $('#program').val()
    $('#specializn').removeAttr("disabled");
    $.ajax({
```

program is the id of first select and specializn is the id of second select.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Please use below code to remove disabled attribute of element.

```
$("#specializn").prop("disabled", false);
```

"The difference between attributes and properties can be important in specific situations. Before jQuery 1.6, the .attr() method sometimes took property values into account when retrieving some attributes, which could cause inconsistent behavior. As of jQuery 1.6, the .prop() method provides a way to explicitly retrieve property values, while  .attr() retrieves attributes."

"Properties generally affect the dynamic state of a DOM element without changing the serialized HTML attribute. Examples include the value property of input elements, the disabled property of inputs and buttons, or the checked property of a checkbox. The .prop() method should be used to set disabled and checked instead of the .attr() method. The .val() method should be used for getting and setting  value."

Comment: Actually there is a change in question.

Comment: Actually there is a change in question. My specialization table's ProgID has  foreign key which is referencing Program table's ProgID primary key, So, I am retrieving the data from a user table to update the records and  when I retrieve data from database my Program Select element is getting populated with the value that was stored in database user table and in that way Specialization table should also get it's value that matches the Program Select's value. But that's not happening it get's enabled but  does not get the value from user table.

Comment: function Update(Rollno) {
      var RollNo = Rollno;
           $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "WebForm1.aspx/UpdateData",
        data: '{rollno: ' + RollNo + '}',
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            $('#rollno').val(data.d[0].RollNo);
            $('#instemail').val(data.d[0].InstituteEmail);
            $('#program').val(data.d[0].ProgID);
            $('#specializn').val(data.d[0].SpeclznID);
            $('#firstname').val(data.d[0].StudentFName);

Comment: Hi the data you are sending ajax request are wrong. Can you please use this data: {rollno:  RollNo }, instead of your current one.

Comment: And one more thing if you still not populate dropdown. Can you please whether you are getting records from ajax file or not.